# Como adicionar um ícone dentro de um TextBox usando Material Design?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Eu instalei o pacote do Material Design Xaml no meu projeto, porém estou com uma dúvida de como criar um ícone no TextBox.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox
    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledTextFieldTextBox}"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    MaxWidth="400"
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Test">
 </TextBox>
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Margin="0,-50,0,0" Kind="User" Foreground="#3e4147" Height="50" Width="50"/>
</StackPanel>
```

porém não funciona, eu procuro fazer igual imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `Canvas`, pois permite deslocar os elementos para qualquer canto.

Utilize o `padding` no seu `textbox` para deixar um espaço no lado esquerdo.

É importante deixar o `materialDesign` na linha de cima para sobrepor o `textbox`

```
<Canvas>
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Heart" Foreground="#3e4147" Height="30" Width="30" Canvas.Left="156" Canvas.Top="34"/>
    <TextBox
        Padding="34 0 0 0"
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFilledTextFieldTextBox}"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        AcceptsReturn="True"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        MaxWidth="400"
        materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Label" Width="451" Canvas.Left="147" Canvas.Top="10"/>
</Canvas>
```

O resultado final será este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, realmente o Canvas ajudou muito, estou começando agora em WPF tem alguma wiki boa para seguir tirando a da microsoft ?

Comment: Eu gosto bastante desse site https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/Localization/LanguageStatus/pt/ ele explica todos os elementos e o que cada um faz